# Can't add Authenticated Routes to react router dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I currently use `react-router-dom` to separate routing for authenticated/non-authenticated people. But Element has an error for missing the properties.

How can `withoutAuth()` work for authentication routes?

> Type '() => Element' is missing the following properties from type 'ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor>': type, props, key

```
function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <AuthProvider>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />
          <Route path="/" element={withoutAuth(<Signup />)} />
        </Routes>
      </AuthProvider>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

const withoutAuth = (Element: ElementType) =>
  function WithoutAuth() {
    const { currentFBUser } = useAuthContext()
    if (currentFBUser) {
      return <Navigate to="/dashboard" />
    }
    return <Element />
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't generally pass JSX literals to Higher Order Components, and the `element` prop takes a JSX literal instead of a reference to a React component.

```
// (1) Create a new decorated component
const SignUpWithoutAuth = withoutAuth(Signup);

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <AuthProvider>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />
          // (2) Pass the new decorated component as JSX to `element` prop
          <Route path="/" element={<SignUpWithoutAuth />} />
        </Routes>
      </AuthProvider>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

This being said, it would be more conventional to implement as a wrapper component than a HOC in RRDv6.

Example:

```
function WithoutAuth({ children }) {
  const { currentFBUser } = useAuthContext()
  if (currentFBUser) {
    return <Navigate to="/dashboard" />
  }
  return children;
}

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <AuthProvider>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />
          <Route
            path="/"
            element={(
              <WithoutAuth>
                <Signup />
              </WithoutAuth>
            )}
          />
        </Routes>
      </AuthProvider>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

Either should work.